# why greater number is below on y-axis when I using matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python

I read the data from a csv.file using pandas.read_csv(). Since the data file contains multiple records, I only plot data related to the plot.
As the plot below, the top number is smaller than the 79 but the plot put it higher. How could I change parameters to make the plot normal?
[image]

1    38.8601776787174

2    67.9876506204439

3    79.6575498473462

4    55.4554563564545

Comment: Can you please post more of your code?

Comment: @GKE I just read data from a file, e.g., data = pd.read_csv("xxx") and I have already posted some records. However I'm not sure if it is enough to find where the problem is.

Comment: Just a wild guess: your data is not float but actually still string because you didn't convert it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're converting from a string, especially if you're reading from a file.

This is the graph I got with a standard plot of floating points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([38.8601776787174 , 67.9876506204439 , 79.6575498473462 , 55.4554563564545])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

[image]

And here it is when only one of the values is a string:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([38.8601776787174 , 67.9876506204439 , 79.6575498473462 , str(55.4554563564545)])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Make sure to convert to int or float before plotting.

Comment: The samples are slicing from the dataframe so it is object/ Series instead of float.It is just what you say, but just not string.

Comment: I assumed it was string given you were reading them from a file, without seeing the full code I wouldn't be able to tell. At any rate you need to have them converted to floats/ints, if it's a non numerical type, you'll get a straight nonsensical line like above , with a nonsensical y-axis.

Comment: Got it. I have already convert the this column to numerical. Thanks.